# Unable to create SSL certificates for parse.com

Tags: ssl, certificate, parse-platform, configure

At parse.com they suggest to upload public certificate first, then upload private key. When I contact SSL vendors they ask me to generate CSR first, but I can't do that without accessing parse.com server. What's the right way of making SSL certificate for parse.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate a CSR without accessing Parse, and then upload the eventual certificate and key.

The web server type used is Nginx.  Here's a link to Digicert, where they have a tool for creating this:  http://www.digicert.com/csr-creation-nginx.htm

Where they say to use your 'server', just use your own computer..  openssl exists for most/all platforms.